# Getting previous working days data from list of dates in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have the following dataframes:

```
longweekend
Out[20]: 
               Day
Date              
2011-04-22  Friday
2011-08-15  Monday
2011-11-07  Monday
2012-02-20  Monday
2012-04-06  Friday
           ...
2020-05-25  Monday
2020-10-02  Friday
2020-11-16  Monday
2020-11-30  Monday
2020-12-25  Friday

[63 rows x 1 columns]
```

And :

```
df1
Out[29]: 
                   High          Low  ...      Volume    Adj Close
Date                                  ...                         
1999-12-31  1472.420044  1458.189941  ...   374050000  1469.250000
2000-01-03  1478.000000  1438.359985  ...   931800000  1455.219971
2000-01-04  1455.219971  1397.430054  ...  1009000000  1399.420044
2000-01-05  1413.270020  1377.680054  ...  1085500000  1402.109985
2000-01-06  1411.900024  1392.099976  ...  1092300000  1403.449951
                ...          ...  ...         ...          ...
2020-05-26  3021.719971  2988.169922  ...  5837060000  2991.770020
2020-05-27  3036.250000  2969.750000  ...  6371230000  3036.129883
2020-05-28  3068.669922  3023.399902  ...  5402670000  3029.729980
2020-05-29  3049.169922  2998.610107  ...  7275080000  3044.310059
2020-06-01  3062.179932  3031.540039  ...  2501351434  3055.729980

[5136 rows x 6 columns]
```

How can i get the `open` from`df1` of the dates from `longweekend` 1 working day before. For example the first date in `longweekend` is `2011-04-22` thus what is the `open` value in `df1` of 1 day before so thursday `2011-04-21`. Or the next one where it is `monday` thus what is the value of open of `Friday` which is `2011-08-12`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
df1.reindex(longweekend.index - pd.to_timedelta('1D')) ['open']
```

You can also do fancy things like:

```
before_after = np.where(longweekend.Day=='Friday',
                        - pd.to_timedelta('1D'),     # Friday - day before
                        pd.to_timedelta('1D')        # Monday - day after
                        )

 df1.reindex(longweekend.index + before_after)['open']
```

Comment: I am getting this error: `KeyError: 'Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is no longer supported, see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#deprecate-loc-reindex-listlike'`